# How to debug Bootloader Qemu ARM?

Tags: arm, qemu, bootloader, low-level

I'm trying to boot a kernel (extracted from a firmware) using QEMU.

Qemu emulation seems to start at `0x0`.

The problem is that the memory from `0x0` to `0x04000000` is only filled with `0`.

How can i debug the bootloader?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what your command line is. The address where QEMU starts execution depends on many things:

- the guest CPU architecture
- which board model you are emulating
- whether you passed QEMU a BIOS image file
- the file format of any file passed to -kernel (ELF, plain kernel image, uImage, etc)

In general, though, you should not expect to be able to pull a random kernel image out of a firmware dump for a piece of Arm hardware and run it under QEMU. This is because every Arm board or machine is different -- RAM may be in different places, the devices such as the serial port are at different addresses, and so on -- and the kernel will only boot on systems which it has been compiled to support. The chances are very high that (a) QEMU does not have a specific emulation of the bit of hardware that the firmware dump is for and (b) the kernel from the firmware has not been built to also run on any of the board types that QEMU does support. So it will almost certainly simply crash very early on in bootup without producing any output.

If you want to debug what's going on in early bootup, the best approach is probably to use QEMU's built in gdbstub, and attach a guest-architecture-aware gdb to it. You may also find QEMU's internal logging via the '-d' option useful, though it requires some familiarity with how QEMU works to make sense of the output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Im using the the following machine command `-M versatileab` with my kernel `-kernel kernel.out`. The kernel is extracted from the firmware using the cmd from an upgrade script of the filesystem `dd if="$image" of=kernel.out ibs=1 obs=1M count="$count" skip=12`. The filesystem contains some binaries : `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV)`. Do you have some doc which explain difference between boards ? There is a lot of information and im new with ARM. What should i focus on to go forward ?

Comment: EDIT : Using `versatileab` i see qemu jumping from `0x0c` to `0x10000` (my kernel).

Comment: Each board is different -- you would need to look up the documentation for the hardware it is emulating. VersatileAB is a very very old development board. It is almost certainly nothing like the hardware your firmware kernel is expecting. https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM has some suggestions on picking a board type.